# ASP.NET MVC authentication cookie not working correctly when deployed to hostgator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 identity authentication cookie in my site. In my local environment the authentication is working correctly.

Also when I deployed my site to goddady shared hosting plesk everything works fine.

However, when I deploy the exact same site to hostgator shared hosting, after logging in, the user is redirected back to login page after trying to access any of the controller actions. In the request I see `Asp.Authentication.Cookie` being sent as part of the request header, however, I get a 302 response from the server and the user is redirected to login page (because I think the authorisation fails).

I cannot figure out why this would happen.

Below is my startup.auth:

```
// Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });

// Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

and the sign in method used when logging in:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

var identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

This is sample request made after logging in:

[image]

The response is 302

**Update**

I wonder if it is IIS version issue, as godday is using v8.5 and hostgator is using v10.

Either way i moved over to bisend.com and had to do away with hostgator

Comment: When configuring your authentication cookie, did you assign a domain? If so, and it doesn't match the Host Gator domain, then subsequent requests to the application won't include that cookie.

Comment: The only place where i configure the cookie is the startup.auth which the first code snippet and the sign method called in the login action which is the second snippet. So i dont set the cookie domain name

Comment: Also as i mentioned i can see the authentication cookie being sent as part of the header, as shown in the attached image. In the above image the cookie is called My cookie, i tried to rename it see if will make any difference

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a WordPress site I had hosted on Hostgator. It was a login and registration site but cookies were not recognised as being set on the frontend homepage. I thought I had managed to change the .htaccess rules for caching from my theme's functions.php file, but it turned out that the .htaccess generated by Hostgator was ignoring these and setting its own rules for optimising the speed of the site.

I commented out the affected caching lines and added

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A1
Header append Cache-Control must-revalidate
```

as per [this site](https://support.tigertech.net/prevent-caching)

The issues I was experiencing went away.